# Getting bad substitution error when bumping up version using maven versions plugin in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline, maven-release-plugin, jenkins-groovy, maven-versions-plugin

I get a bad substitution error when I run this command in my jenkins pipeline

```
sh 'mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
-DnewVersion=${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT \
-DgenerateBackupPoms=false \
-DprocessAllModules \
-DgenerateBackupPoms=false'
```

This is the error message in this case -

> [code] Running shell script
>
> /apps/jenkins/latest/workspace/ess-holani_master-3YNVBB6LFQA3QFK5NHYV57DW5HGSNALVGFJTJ4D6T72QVPJG4CDA/code@tmp/durable-374bc417/script.sh:
>   line 2:
>   -DnewVersion=${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT:
>   bad substitution
>
> script returned exit code 1

But this works ->

```
sh 'mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
-DnewVersion=\\\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT \
-DgenerateBackupPoms=false \
-DprocessAllModules \
-DgenerateBackupPoms=false'
```

This command bumps up my pom version as expected.

Logs on jenkins shell when I run the above command

> [code] Running shell script
>
> mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set '-DnewVersion=${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT'
>   -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -DprocessAllModules -DgenerateBackupPoms=false

Using double quotes also work here -

```
sh "mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
-DnewVersion=\\\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT \
-DgenerateBackupPoms=false \
-DprocessAllModules \
-DgenerateBackupPoms=false"
```

I want to understand why do we need to add an extra '\\\' in this script ?

Answer suggested by michael works .

I also tried this

```
sh "mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
-DnewVersion='\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT' \
-DgenerateBackupPoms=false \
-DprocessAllModules \
-DgenerateBackupPoms=false"
```

I removed \ before the closing ' at the end . This also worked.

Comment: using really single quotes or double quotes in Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: Edited my question to answer.

Comment: Could you kindly post the error when not using the escaped backslash?

Comment: Are you sure the second example (`'`s with `\\\$`) actually worked. I assume that Maven set the version to `\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT` (no substitutions) in that case.

Comment: Edited my question to answer your question.
And yes, it does work as expected with ' and \\\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using three layers of interpreters and compilers and all use the same syntax for variable substitutions in strings: "${myvar}".

1. First there is Groovy, which would give you a bad substitution since it does not know any variable named `parsedVersion.minorVersion`. You can use `'`s instead of `"`s to prevent Groovy to try that or escape the `$` with a `\`. Groovy however will pass `\$` as `$` and `\\\$` as `\$` to the next instance.
2. Second there is the Shell. Again you have the option to use `'` or to escape.
3. Maven and that's the one which you'd like to do the replacement `$`

I think you could go with less confusion, if you'd use `'` around your version string:

```
sh "mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
  -DnewVersion='\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT' \
  -DgenerateBackupPoms=false \
  -DprocessAllModules \
  -DgenerateBackupPoms=false"
```

EDIT: or this one using `'`s so we need to escape the `'`s but don't need to do any escaping on the `$`s:

```
sh 'mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
  -DnewVersion=\'${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT\' \
  -DgenerateBackupPoms=false \
  -DprocessAllModules \
  -DgenerateBackupPoms=false'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I tried the same command after removing the \ before the second '     "\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT' ".  This also worked. The \ escape character is not needed then ?

Comment: @SharadHolani my bad. Removed it from the answer as well. A different idea would be to use `'`s around the whole thing. In that case we'd need to escape the `'`s we'd like to pass to Maven. I however found the `"`s version slightly better readable.

Comment: @SharadHolani I added another version with no `$` escapes, which should work as well.